# Match strings with more than one character in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, regex, google-sheets-query

I have the following query:

```
=QUERY('Data'!A2:F,"SELECT A, B, F WHERE C=''")
```

In column E I also have strings which correspond to last names. I want to select all rows where the string in E has more than one char. 
I've tried using the MATCH and LIKE operators but haven't managed to get it to work. One solution I actively avoided was using an extra column with the LEN function and select based on the values there. I would like the logic to be contained in the query as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can use the `like` operator with query like this:

```
=QUERY(Data!A2:F,"SELECT A, B, F WHERE C='' and E like '__%'")
```

basically `_` means any one character, and `%` means 0 or more characters - so by using 2 instances of `_` before using `%` it requires there be at least more than one characters, while also allowing it the flexibility of using a wildcard.

[image]

Comment: That's it! I was trying just with `=QUERY(Data!A2:F,"SELECT A, B, F WHERE C='' and E like '__'")` and it wasn't working, now I understand why. Thanks!